# Why do some mined transactions not contain a 'to' parameter?

Tags: transactions, blocks

Sometimes there are transactions inside a block that are missing the 'to' field.

How can there be a mined transaction without a to field? What happens to this transaction?

eg. one of the transactions from Mainnet mined in block 16053977:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(16053977, true)

 {
    "blockHash": "0xbb7c000504a062aebe0fba960df4e5155dc29183393f394cdc5d48895273b94b",
    "blockNumber": "0xf4f6d9",
    "hash": "0x29a7002066ce96e17ab0c462e08b0257e0f90468e8b8d683292b10885062e7bb",
    "chainId": "0x1",
    "from": "0xcdd37ada79f589c15bd4f8fd2083dc88e34a2af2",
    "gas": "0x32423",
    "gasPrice": "0x48dae8760",
    "input": "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",
    "nonce": "0x2bb00",
    "r": "0x1730ee39091ff5ee140339630191c61682ab21aad8e2cb50941aee7c30a5668e",
    "s": "0x7f3ccafb1dc04ab44241440c5efe646b161504f406e22a82094c1c87eb443426",
    "transactionIndex": "0xa",
    "type": "0x0",
    "v": "0x26",
    "value": "0x0"
  },
```